# How to install Orange library in web-server?

Tags: orange

I usually use Orange especially python script widget .

For some reason, i want use web server to do my  data mining job.

How  to install Orange library on web server and use it like i use python script widget  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install Orange without the graphical interface, you will have to make everything in scripts (saved workflows will not work).

I have not tested it, but try checking out Orange's git repository (https://github.com/biolab/orange3), modify its setup.py file by replacing

```
requirements = ['requirements-core.txt', 'requirements-gui.txt']
```

with

```
requirements = ['requirements-core.txt’]
```

and then try installing with `pip install .`